# Сокрытие ввода в консоли Python 3

Tags: python, консоль, python-3.x

Здравия.

Мне требуется скрывать вводимые в консоль символы (ввод пароля).

Подскажите, это вообще можно сделать?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import getpass
pw = getpass.getpass()
```