# Реализация скрытого пароля на Python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, безопасность, пароль

Пароль в терминале Linux скрывается при вводе, можно ли такое реализовать на Python, используя обычный `input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот возможное решение:

```
import getpass
pw = getpass.getpass()
```

Вопрос уже был разобран
[вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/280539/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-python-3)