# Ввод пароля, замена символов вводимых в консоли на "*"

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Пишу одну утилиту и есть такой момент когда в запущенной программе требуется ввести пароль. Строка ввода пароля выглядит так

```
password = input("Write the password: ")
```

и больше ничего, соответсвенно введенная таким образом строка будет отображаться для пользователя в консоли. 
А нужно сделать так чтобы введенные символы с клавиатуры отображались в консоли как звездочки(символ "*"), т.е. в консоли при вводе должно быть такое

```
Write the password: *******
```

Pyhton начал изучать совсем недавно и не имею даже примерного представления как это можно осуществить

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/510364/10941639

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сокрытие ввода в консоли Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/280539/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-python-3)

Comment: @Эникейщик в том вопросе говорится о скрытии символов, а мне их надо заменить на *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите библиотеку:

```
pip install Inline-input
```

---

Простой пример:

```
import inline #Импортируем библиотеку
input = inline.input #Заменяем стандартный input

name = input("Пароль: ", secret=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вы также можете ограничить длину пароля, и сделать ещё множество других вещей, [подробнее.](https://pypi.org/project/Inline-input/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Из коробки есть модуль для ввода паролей [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html), но в нем не показывается ввод пароля:

```
from getpass import getpass
password = getpass()
print(password)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import getpass
import sys

if sys.stdin.isatty():
    p = getpass.getpass('Using getpass: ')
else:
    print('Using readline')
    p = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()

print('Read: ', p)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
password = input("Write the password: ")
print(f"Write the password: {'*'*len(password)} ")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это вообще не то.